# MySQL or PHP is appending a Â whenever the £ is used

Tags: php, mysql, character

Answers provided have all been great, I mentioned in the comments of Alnitak's answer that I would need to go take a look at my CSV Generation script because for whatever reason it wasn't outputting UTF-8.

As was correctly pointed out, it WAS outputting UTF-8 - the problem existed with Ye Olde Microsoft Excel which wasn't picking up the encoding the way I would have liked.

My existing CSV generation looked something like:

```
// Create file and exit;
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
echo $csv_output;
```

It now looks like:

```
// Create file and exit;
$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");

echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $csv_output);
```

### -------------------------------------------------------

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Hi,

I've got a form which collects data, form works ok but I've just noticed that if someone types or uses a '£' symbol, the MySQL DB ends up with 'Â£'.

Not really sure where or how to stop this from happening, code and DB information to follow:

**MySQL details**

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM fraud_report;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | mediumint(9) |      | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| crm_number   | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| datacash_ref | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount       | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sales_date   | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| domain       | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_added   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| agent_added  | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

**PHP Function**

```
function    processFraudForm($crm_number, $datacash_ref, $amount, $sales_date, $domain, $agent_added) {

    // Insert Data to DB
    $sql    = "INSERT INTO fraud_report (id, crm_number, datacash_ref, amount, sales_date, domain, date_added, agent_added) VALUES (NULL, '$crm_number', '$datacash_ref', '$amount', '$sales_date', '$domain', NOW(), '$agent_added')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    if ($result) {
        $outcome = "<div id=\"success\">Emails sent and database updated.</div>";
    } else {
        $outcome = "<div id=\"error\">Something went wrong!</div>";
    }

    return $outcome;
}
```

**Example DB Entry**

```
+----+------------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | crm_number | datacash_ref | amount  | sales_date | domain             | date_added          | agent_added      |
+----+------------+--------------+---------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 13 | 100xxxxxxx | 10000000     | Â£10.93 | 18/12/08   |  blargh.com        | 2008-12-22 10:53:53 | agent.name |
```

Comment: I guess you've learnt something here. But, there is a very good beginners article at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html - 'The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)' -- It gives context to how and why character encoding is the way it is and how it works.

Comment: I see you've already read that. But, I'll let the comment remain. Its a good resource to understand what character encoding is about.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you're seeing is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding - it's a way of storing Unicode characters in a relatively compact format.

The pound symbol has value `0x00a3` in Unicode, but when it's written in UTF-8 that becomes `0xc2 0xa3` and that's what's stored in the database.  It seems that your database table is already set to use UTF-8 encoding.  This is a *good thing*!

If you pull the value back out from the database and display it on a UTF-8 compatible terminal (or on a web page that's declared as being UTF-8 encoded) it will look like a normal pound sign again.

Comment: Thanks, learn something new everyday, now to figure out how to make my CSV generation script output UTF-8 :)

Comment: if you're outputting CSV and it contains the C2A3 sequence, it already *is* UTF-8 - whatever reads the CSV needs to understand it or be told to expect UTF-8.

Comment: The pound sign is 0xA3 in an Ansi code page and 0x00A3 in Unicode, which is why the character appeared mostly normal in the DB. But in general, the UTF-8 version of non-ASCII characters doesn't work out so nicely.

Comment: indeed - it's a coincidence that the second byte of the UTF-8 encoding of 0xA3 also happens to be 0xA3 !

Comment: Not really a coincidence if you look at how the encoding works. Any 8 bit character in decimal range 128-191 has the first two binary digits as 10, which is the same as the UTF-8 lead bits, thus char n in that range is encoded as 0xC2 n

Comment: Got to be honest and say the encoding stuff has gone a little over my head, but combined with http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=91448&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a - issue sorted. Question updated above for other eedgits like me!

Comment: ok, it's not a *real* coincidence, yes anything from 128 - 191 would do that.  The coincidence is that the OP happened to see one of that relatively small set of characters where this is true.

Answer (score 8):

Â£ is 0xC2 0xA3 which is the UTF-8 encoding for £ symbol - so you're storing it as UTF-8, but presumably viewing it as Latin-1 or something other than UTF-8

It's useful to know how to spot and decode UTF-8 by hand - check the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for info on how the encoding works:

- 0xC2A3 = 110 **00010**  10 **100011**
- The bold parts are the actual
  "payload", which gives 10100011,
  which is 0xA3, the pound symbol.

Comment: Thanks, good answer which helped me understand the why - Alnitak got the Accepted because it helped me understand the how-to-fix! +1upvote

Answer (score 7):

In PHP, another small scale solution is to do a string conversion on the returned utf8 string:

```
print iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', "Mystring â"); //"Mystring "
```

Or in other platforms fire a system call to the inconv command (linux / osx)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#83238

Answer (score 2):

You need to serve your HTML in utf-8 encoding (actually everyone needs to do this I think!)
Header like:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Or the  equivalent.  Double check the details though.  Should always be declaring the charset as a browser can default to anything it likes.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a Â use:

$column = str_replace("\xc2\xa0", '', $column);

Credits among others: [How to remove all occurrences of c2a0 in a string with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923426/how-to-remove-all-occurrences-of-c2a0-in-a-string-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I had been suspecting mysql for being currupting the pound symbol. Now all i need to do is wherever the csv record is generated, just use wrap them incov funciton. Though this is a good job, I am happy, at least someone showed exactly what to do. I sincerly appreciate  dislaying the previous and the new 'header' values. It was a great help to me.

-mark

Answer (score 0):

If you save line "The £50,000 Development Challenge" in two different data type column i.e. "varchar" & "text" field.

Before i save i have replaced the symbol with html equi value using following function. 
str_replace("£", "£", $title);

You will find that value stored in text fields is &pound where as in varchar its "Â£".

Comment: Trying to answer something which is already answered around two years ago seems a little, odd.