# How to remove Â character

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I got very strange problem. I have one php website which is running in two server. One is on Apache (Linux) and second is on IIS (WIndow). Linux Server, I just run it for demo. IIS is the actual hosting that I need to host. Even with all the same code, database, in the linux server, there's no Â character. But in IIS, everywhere got Â characters. I checked all the meta tag, it's utf-8. In database collation is utf-8 also. In mysql database, i got those Â character, but somehow, in linux, when we fetch the content from database, those Â doesn't show. It just happening on IIS. Can anyone point out how can i resolve this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while ago, there are some useful comments and information here - it's PHP but I believe the theory would be the same:[Question 386378](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386378/mysql-or-php-is-appending-a-awhenever-the-is-used)

Comment: seems like, my question is quite hard to understanding. Yeap, what i got the problem is

Those Â character content are displaying everywhere when i am browsing at IIS server.

But in apache (linux) server, it doesn't show any.

All codes that I wrote and the content fetch from the database is totally same.

Comment: So the problem is probably that, while Apache correctly serving the content as UTF-8, IIS is serving it as something else--probably windows-1252.  This is thoroughly covered in the thread that's linked to in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to specify UTF-8 in the HTTP headers. With PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

With Apache:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

The Apache setting can be placed in an **.htaccess** file.

Comment: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8  nice one!

Answer (score 1):

> I checked all the meta tag, it's utf-8.

The browser doesn't interpret the meta tag. It's only a fallback when no http-headers are present. Right click and select "View Page Info" to see what encoding the browser *actually* interprets the page in.

> In database collation is utf-8 also. In mysql database

*Collation* is irrelevant for display of characters. The *charset* matters however. So does the connection charset.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the html responses directly by using something like [Fiddler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) or [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28Firefox_extension%29). Check to see if the responses from IIS/Apache (which should be returning exactly the same text) have:

- Different data
- Different headers

Pay particular attention to the Content-Type header, which should say what character encoding (utf-8, ISO/IEC 8859-1, Latin-1, etc.) the returned text is in.