# Registered Symbol Problem with Flash Mailto Link

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

The problem I'm having is an extra Â Chracter being added before the ® symbol in the body of an email created from a mailto: link in flash. This only happens on the PC in MS Outlook

Instead of:
MasterCard®!

It shows up as

MasterCardÂ®!

The code in flash AS3:

```
var req = new URLRequest("mailto:");
var variables = new URLVariables();
variables.body="Blah Blah Blah MasterCard®!";
variables.subject="Make some music!";
req.data = variables;
req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent) {
        navigateToURL(req, "_self");
    }
}
```

This works fine on the mac with mac mail.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are changing the encoding of the text make sure that what you are sending it to is working in the same encoding as you are sending.

check out similar posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386378/mysql-or-php-is-appending-a-a-whenever-the--is-used) for an explination.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue after url encode in JavaScript.

This is how I fixed it.

```
var content = encodeURIComponent(emailBody); // encode the email body to send to email client via mailto:
content = content.replace("%C3%82", ""); // remove the junk char before reg symbol which was inserted during encoding.
```

`%C3%82` is causing the issue `Â` , so I replaced and its worked fine.

Please note that this is JavaScript code, you need to check how to do it in ActionScript