# email formatting

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL or PHP is appending a Â whenever the £ is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386378/mysql-or-php-is-appending-a-a-whenever-the--is-used)

I get the letter Â when I send email using php mail...

it appear before £ sign..

can anyone help ?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386378/mysql-or-php-is-appending-a-a-whenever-the--is-used

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate but I regret it. Specifying character encodings in e-mail is a different matter than specifying it in web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the correct content type i.e `mail($to,$subject,$message,"Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8")`

Hope this helps