# php mysql flex unicode

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, unicode

I have a problem with saving the £ symbol to a mysql database.

1. I am running a flex front end, with a php + mysql backend
2. When I save a record from flex, the string gets sent to the server as "This amount is £10"
3. php views the string as above, and when it gets saved into the DB, it gets saved as "This amount is Â£10". My understanding is that this is correct based on [MySQL or PHP is appending a Â whenever the £ is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386378/mysql-or-php-is-appending-a-a-whenever-the--is-used)
4. I now retrieve the above record, and it gets sent to flex as "This amount is Â£10". Flex correctly displays this in a textarea as "This amount is £10"
5. I change another field in the same record in flex, and re-save the transaction. The string now gets sent to the server as "This amount is Â£10"
6. The record is now saved into the DB as "The amount is Ã‚Â£10". Each time the record is re-saved, this effect snowballs.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: At the end of the day, this seemed to be an amfphp issue, as discovered at http://ghalex.com/blog/as3flexdb-and-utf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, this seemed to be an amfphp issue, as discovered at ghalex.com/blog/as3flexdb-and-utf8

Answer (score 0):

use the unicode £ in replacement of the £ sign before you insert to MySQL.

check your database charset? That could be the issue.

Comment: Database collation is set to utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me as a charset issue. I haven't used flex, I use Dojo forms with Zend Framework and Doctrine 2 that handles everything in utf-8 format.

Try setting everything to utf-8:

1. mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
2. add in your header: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />

I've had similar issues when the form is ISO-8859-1, you can also try the php funciton: utf8_encode() when getting the values from the form. Sometimes I've found it hard to find the ISO-8859-1 source and then I usually try to debug using the decode/encode functions.