# How to remove all occurrences of c2a0 in a string with PHP?

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I'm working with a CSV file which is exported from Excel.

I have a column that contains a value of 1 234,00. I need to get all whitespaces away from these kinds of columns with PHP and I've tried to do it with `preg_replace("/\s*/","",$column)` as well as with `str_replace(" ","",$column)`. I was almost ready to lose it so I took a glance into the csv-file with a HEX-editor and noticed, that this space consist of two hex values, C2 and A0 which seems to be UTF-8 non-breaking space.

But I suck with encoding stuff and I'm still confused in finding a way to remove them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$column = str_replace("\xc2\xa0", '', $column);
```

Comment: To whom it may be interested this works because the input is UTF-8, if the input is ISO-8895-1 or CP1252 you must use `str_replace("\xA0", '', $column);` Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33019796/260080

Comment: @MarcoDemaio Or better first, [convert to UTF-8 first](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php). Any application that works with ISO-8859-1 internally is buggy – for instance, it will not correctly handle emojis.

Comment: Beware that if `$column` was `null`, it will become an empty string.

Answer (score 17):

You may use `trim`

```
trim($data['value'], " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xc2\xa0")
```

Where `\t\n\r\0\x0B` is defualt mask, `\xc2\xa0` need add

Comment: [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) also includes space in the default mask — `" \t\n\r\0\x0B\xc2\xa0"`.

Comment: This might remove parts of an otherwise correct multibyte character.
`var_dump("\xc2\xb4AAAA"); var_dump(trim("\xc2\xb4AAAA", " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xc2\xa0"));`