# How to remove NBSP?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, excel, unicode

Using PHP to do a  `file_get_contents` on a *.txt file.  Then inserting the data into MySQL. Values are inserting null. The null is caused by a non breaking space and a replacement charcter from an excel export. I figured that by copying the characters from the text file into a [unicode inspector](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=) .
Did the same with the replacement character. Copied the text and pasted it [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BF%BD) to confirm.

Tried many `str_replace` and `preg_replace` but no luck. Tried nearly everything on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837682/non-breaking-utf-8-0xc2a0-space-and-preg-replace-strange-behaviour) question and found this worked.

```
$some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces = "Christ  O'Connory";
$clean_text = hex2bin(str_replace('c2a0', '20', bin2hex($some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces)));
echo $clean_text;
```

BUT it didn't when I put it inline with the `file_get_contents()` method.

Any idea how to resolve the null value with `preg_replace`, `str_replace` or other methods?

Here's all the versions I've tried:

```
$name = str_replace('\A0\00', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = str_replace('c2a0', '20', $nbsp);
$name = str_replace('\xc2\xa0', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = str_replace('~\xc2\xa0~', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = str_replace('\xC2\xA0', ' ',$nbsp);
$name = str_replace('&amp;nbsp;', ' ',$nbsp);
$name = hex2bin(str_replace('c2a0', '20', bin2hex($nbsp)));  // this did work but not when putting inline with original code.
$name = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z\,\.\'\-\_]#', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('\x{00a0}', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('~\x00\xa0~', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('~\xc2\xa0~', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('\s\s+', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',  $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('~\x{c2a0}~siu', ' ',  $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('/\s/u', ' ',  $nbsp);
$name = preg_replace('/[^\w\d\p{L}]/u', ' ',$nbsp);
```

Here is a snippet of data from the file I was attempting to do a file_get_contents on.

```
SupervisorGivenName SupervisorSurName   row_date    logid   item_name   acdcalls    AHT AvgHoldTime transferred CntOBCalls  calls
        Ders    Schmid  09/02/2015  5054589 Christ  O'Connory   26  420 112 4   0   0
        Nic Flemg   09/02/2015  5054596 Mica  Wit   28  543 32  6   0   0



    Insert statement:

        $bb_query = "INSERT INTO `tier1_bb_agent_daily` (`date`,`loginID`,`empID`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`supID`, `supName`,`acd_calls`,`paetec_acd_calls`,`aht`,`avg_hold_time`,`transferred`,`outbound_call_count`)
                        VALUES ('{$row['date']}','{$row['loginID']}','{$empID}','{$firstname}','{$lastname}','{$supid}','{$newSupName}',{$row['acd_calls']},{$row['paetec_acd_calls']},{$row['aht']},{$row['avg_hold_time']},{$row['transferred']},{$row['outbound_call_count']})
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE firstname = '{$firstname}', lastname = '{$lastname}',empID = '{$empID}', supID = '{$supid}', supName = '{$newSupName}',acd_calls = {$row['acd_calls']}, aht = {$row['aht']}, paetec_acd_calls = {$row['paetec_acd_calls']}, avg_hold_time = {$row['avg_hold_time']}, transferred = {$row['transferred']}, outbound_call_count = {$row['outbound_call_count']}";
                $db->query($bb_query);
```

Comment: and `$nbsp` is defined as? plus file content is?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's a non-breaking space

Comment: @MattJamison the question you linked has an answer which uses `~\x{00a0}~siu` while in your version you didn't add the modifiers. Working with the `u` modifier is crucial when working with unicode.

Comment: @HamZa that didn't work either.

Comment: You are using **$nbsp** and **$name** (two variables); If you want to replace it in the string, you have to use the same variable name for the next replace. Hope that helps.

@OP: did check printing the result just after file_get_contents and just before inserting itt into DB?

Comment: Does anybody understand this question? I feel very stupid... Explain me please what is the problem OP faced with? and what is his expected result? The question looks like a set of words with no sense to me

Comment: @Alex: this is how I understood, OP is getting some text from some text file and inserting it into a database, record getting inserted but with null.

Comment: Is it double encoded? `$name = str_replace('&amp;nbsp;', ' ',$nbsp);`

Comment: @PixelMaker but where is his query then? where is table structure? where is the php code that realize that functionality?

Comment: @MattJamison: did you check printing the result after file_get_contents and just before inserting it into DB?

Comment: No one can answer the question without knowing what `$nbsp` is.

Comment: @chris85 according to `mysql` tag, I would try to answer without knowing `$nbsp` because the problem is some `null`  appeared somewhere on mysql side ;-) :-)

Comment: @PixelMaker I did not check right after file_get_contents.  I will though. Just found out the nbsp came from an Excel sheet. The data provider is going to clean it up so I don't have to code around it.  So not sure I'll ever get the answer.

Comment: @MattJamison you never provided a reproducible example of the issue here so we won't be able to help you...

Comment: @chris85 I would have but I had no where to upload the text file that I was doing a file_get_contents.  :( for the down vote.

Comment: Okay so that sample bit is `$nbsp`? Can you also include the code you're inserting with?

Comment: @chris85 add the insert statement.

Comment: You need to use prepared statements. As your sample data shows `O'Connory` will break your query because the `'` ends the SQL string encapsulation. `Connory` and all other string values are all offset from being quoted.

Comment: @chris85  I'm cleaning the data before insert to account for apostrophe's hyphens etc.  before inserting. I just left that code out of the question.

Comment: It is very difficult to know what you are doing..

Comment: `UPDATE tbl SET col = REPLACE(col, '&nbsp;', ' ');`  should handle all cases in one column of one table.

Answer (score 4):

### Why most of your attempts failed

```
$name = str_replace('\A0\00', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = str_replace('c2a0', '20', $nbsp);
```

Wrong escape sequences.

```
$name = str_replace('~\xc2\xa0~', ' ', $nbsp);
```

The delimiters are needed for regexes, not for simple string replacement.

```
$name = str_replace('\xc2\xa0', ' ', $nbsp);
$name = str_replace('\xC2\xA0', ' ',$nbsp);
```

Correct escape sequences, but [you need *double-quoted strings* for escape sequences to work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
$name = str_replace('&amp;nbsp;', ' ',$nbsp);
```

Only works for HTML entities.

```
$name = preg_replace('#[A-Za-z\,\.\'\-\_]#', ' ', $nbsp);
```

Why would you want to replace A-Z with space?

```
$name = preg_replace('\x{00a0}', ' ', $nbsp);
```

Missing delimiters and Unicode modifier.

```
$name = preg_replace('~\x00\xa0~', ' ', $nbsp);
```

Tries to match NUL characters, missing Unicode modifier.

```
$name = preg_replace('~\xc2\xa0~', ' ', $nbsp);
```

**This one should have worked for UTF-8.** It's equivalent to the `bin2hex` hack.

```
$name = preg_replace('\s\s+', ' ', $nbsp);
```

Missing regex delimiters.

```
$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',  $nbsp);
```

Missing Unicode modifier.

```
$name = preg_replace('~\x{c2a0}~siu', ' ',  $nbsp);
```

Wrong escape sequence.

```
$name = preg_replace('/\s/u', ' ',  $nbsp);
```

This one should work but replaces every whitespace character with space.

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^\w\d\p{L}]/u', ' ',$nbsp);
```

Should work but also replaces punctuation with space.

### How to replace non-breaking space with normal space

If your input is encoded as UTF-8 (which it probably is if the `bin2hex` hack worked):

```
$result = str_replace("\xC2\xA0", ' ', $src); # or
$result = preg_replace('/\xC2\xA0/', ' ', $src); # or
$result = preg_replace('/\xA0/u', ' ', $src);
```

If your input is encoded as ISO-8859-1:

```
$result = str_replace("\xA0", ' ', $src); # or
$result = preg_replace('/\xA0/', ' ', $src);
```

The `str_replace` versions are preferred for performance reasons.

Comment: These are good for the nbsp. What about for the replacement character coming from excel?

Comment: Excellent and very informative answer! +1

Answer (score -2):

Just debug your code
print the file contents after file_get_contents

```
$file_contents** = file_get_contents(......);
echo 'File Contents '."\n\n";
print_r($file_contents);
$modified = str_replace('\A0\00', ' ', $file_contents);
$modified = str_replace('c2a0', '20', $modified);
$modified = str_replace('\xc2\xa0', ' ', **$modified);

..................
echo 'Before DB'."\n\n";
print_r($modified);
//your insert here
```