# How to deal with UTF-8 vs. Latin-1 encoding issues in PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to store GPS `latitude` and `longitude` value in DMS format with the `degree` and `apostrophe` in `mysql` with `php`.

The previous solution is `convert it into Decimal`.

Is there any particular `datatype` to store the value in `mysql` with the symbols like below:

```
12°53′17″N
80°13′52″E
```

The proble is,it replaces with `12Â°53â€²17â€³ N`, `80Â°13â€²52â€³ E`.

Comment: In that exact format? It would have to be a string type like `nvarchar()`. But most commonly latitude and longitude are stored as decimals, as you said is already the case.

Comment: thanks.. but it doesn't help me..

Comment: @m2j, it probably doesn't do that, it's just that you haven't figured out how text encoding / character sets work.

Comment: @m2j *"Is there any particular datatype to store the value in mysql with the symbols like below"*. I answered the question you asked. If it isn't helpful, ask a different question.

Comment: if you format lil bit like instead of `′` use single quot `'` then you can store like this `12°53'17''N`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL or PHP is appending a Â whenever the £ is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386378/mysql-or-php-is-appending-a-%c3%82-whenever-the-%c2%a3-is-used)

Answer (score 1):

Create your table by setting the character set as `utf-UTF-8 Unicode`. If you specify the Character set for the table as Unicode then it will accept the original latitude/longitude Values. 
Reference code for SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `gps`
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

The following works for me

```
CREATE TABLE `gps` (
  `lat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: using php there are lots of way, replace the `′` with single quotation `'`, or use string escaping by inserting back slash `\` for `′` and `″`, remember these are not single quot and double quot. using PHP we can replace any string in between three values and explode then at the time of operation and then convert them in decimal too.